# How to add Kingfisher for a UIImage without a URL in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, kingfisher

I have added Kingfisher to an UI Image in a tableview cell but it does not work properly. The below is the example of the code that I have tried previously,

```
directoryPresenter!.getProfileImage(id:(directoryPresenter!.getEmployeeItem(position: indexPath.row).employeeID)) { image in
      cell.profileImage.kf.base.image = image
   // cell.profileImage.image = image
}
```

Can we add Kingfisher to an UI Image without passing an URL. Most of the questions I found was related to URLs. Please help me to figure out the issue

Comment: Are you showing online Image or locally saved image ?

Comment: What does "I have added Kingfisher to an UI Image in a tableview cell" mean?  How do you add Kingfisher to a `UIImage` object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a locally saved image, you don't need to use Kingfisher, just do it like this:

```
cell.profileImage.image = image
```

if you want to show image using a url, do it like this:

```
cell.profileImage.kf.setImage(with: {imageURL})
```